# iPhone-SDK: How to make iPhone format website?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to make my own website as iPhone friendly format when user launches my website in an iPhone browser?
Currently if i launch my website in iPhone, it doesn't look more readable and i need to zoom it to see clearly. If i want to provide my website link will be more clear and readable with bold fonts and buttons ( moreover it is like iPhone friendly format) in the first launch itself in iPhone browser, how to make it success? I could able to see some third party websites like http://tringapps.com and all provide the same logic. How to achieve this and what should i do for that? Where to code?

Clave/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make a separate version, or at the very least an extreme re-CSSing of your existing site.

Apple has some good tips on getting started [here](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html).

There are several toolkits to assist in developing the web apps as well, [like this](http://code.google.com/p/iui/) and [even this](http://code.google.com/p/ciui-dev/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a good book to get started. [Building Applications for Mobile Safari](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-iPhone-iPod-touch-Programming)
There are many PDFs available from Apple.